# Want to call an api aftter 30 sec of the app going to the background in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an api call after 30 seconds of the app goes to the background, Using AppState from react-native, i can take the callback when the app goes to the background but not getting any callback after 30 sec using setTimeOut() function, what to do for that please help, I am new to react-native.My tried code

```
 useEffect(() => {
    let backgroundTimer;
    const handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
        if (nextAppState === 'background') {console.log("your app goes to the background")
            backgroundTimer = setTimeout(() => {
                fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => console.log('API Response:', data))
                    .catch(error => console.error('API Error:', error));
            }, 30000);
        } else {
            clearTimeout(backgroundTimer);
        }
    };
    AppState.addEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);
    return () => {
        AppState.removeEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);
        clearTimeout(backgroundTimer);
    };
}, []);
```

Comment: Please share the code you have tried with. Stack Overflow can help you troubleshoot existing code, not write it for you. To learn more about how the community can help you, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @millerluki edited

Answer (score 1):

You can use react-native-background-timer module for this.First install using
`npm install react-native-background-timer`
Then your App component should look like this

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { AppState } from 'react-native';
import BackgroundTimer from 'react-native-background-timer';

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    let backgroundTimer;

    const handleAppStateChange = (newState) => {
      if (newState === 'background') {
        // Schedule your task after 30 seconds
        backgroundTimer = BackgroundTimer.setTimeout(() => {
          // Your API call or any background task
          console.log('Executing task after 30 seconds in the background');
        }, 30000);
      } else {
        // Clear the timer when the app is in the foreground
        BackgroundTimer.clearTimeout(backgroundTimer);
      }
    };

    // Subscribe to app state changes
    AppState.addEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);

    return () => {
      // Unsubscribe from app state changes when the component unmounts
      AppState.removeEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    // Your component JSX
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting a timeout when the app goes into the background, but when the app comes back to the foreground, you're clearing that timeout and the timeout is not being set again when the app comes back to the foreground.

I will simplify your code.

```
const makeApiCall = () => {
 fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(data => console.log('API Response:', data))
   .catch(error => console.error('API Error:', error));
}

useEffect(() => {
 let backgroundTimer;
 const handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
   if (nextAppState === 'background') {
     console.log("your app goes to the background");
     backgroundTimer = setTimeout(makeApiCall, 30000);
   } else if (nextAppState === 'active') {
     backgroundTimer = setTimeout(makeApiCall, 30000);
   } else {
     clearTimeout(backgroundTimer);
   }
 };
 AppState.addEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);
 return () => {
   AppState.removeEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);
   clearTimeout(backgroundTimer);
 };
}, []);
```

Here, you can extract the API call into a separate function and call that function whenever you need to set the timeout.

Comment: problem is that api is not call after 30 sec of going the app to the background even for the first time app goes to the background

Comment: How about remove ```else if``` then? so the api call is only made after 30 seconds when the app goes to the background.

Comment: yes only need api call for after 30 sec of the app goes to the background